# axios interception on request callback not working

Tags: javascript, https, axios, interceptor

I have following code

```
import {AxiosError, AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse} from "axios";
import { request } from "http";

const onRequest = (config: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosRequestConfig => {
    console.log('in-2')
    console.info(`[request] [${JSON.stringify(config)}]`);
    config = {...config,baseURL :"https://api.test.com",headers: { ...config.headers,...{'Authorization':"token"} } }
    return config;
}
//process.env.REACT_API_URL

const onRequestError = (error: AxiosError): Promise<AxiosError> => {
    console.error(`[request error] [${JSON.stringify(error)}]`);
    return Promise.reject(error);
}

const onResponse = (response: AxiosResponse): AxiosResponse => {
    console.info(`[response] [${JSON.stringify(response)}]`);
    return response;
}

const onResponseError = (error: AxiosError): Promise<AxiosError> => {
    console.error(`[response error] [${JSON.stringify(error)}]`);
    return Promise.reject(error);
}

export function setupInterceptorsTo(axiosInstance: AxiosInstance): AxiosInstance {
    console.log('in',axiosInstance)
    axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(onRequest,onRequestError  );
    axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(onResponse, onResponseError);
    return axiosInstance;
}
```

then

```
import {setupInterceptorsTo} from "./Interceptors";
import axios from "axios";
setupInterceptorsTo(axios)
export default  axios.create();
```

But onRequest callback never executing

I also tried like

```
import {setupInterceptorsTo} from "./Interceptors";
import axios from "axios";
setupInterceptorsTo(axios)
export default  axios.create({baseURL :"https://api.test.com"});
```

But still neither onRequest or onRequestError  callback working, as I am giving dummy API call which is throwing error on console.

I believe onRequest should be called before any request so that we can modify request, and onRequestError should be called if any error including 404,

Is my thinking wrong.

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: Based on documentation: https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors, a possible solution would be `export default setupInterceptorsTo(axios.create({baseURL :"https://api.test.com"}))`